# jq - nested dictionary parser and extract key

Tags: json, filter, jq

I am trying to parse with jq the following structure:

```
{
    "a": {
        "sensitive": false,
        "type": "string",
        "value": "mykeypair"
    },
    "b": {
        "sensitive": false,
        "type": "string",
        "value": "123"
    }
}
```

and get this as an output:

```
{
        "a": "mykeypair",
        "b": "123"
}
```

I would like the key and as a value, the value of the field 'value'.
Any idea?
Cheers,

Comment: What is your question? That is, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Guessing from the title that you want the keys only? See https://jqplay.org/s/KpW40peoTH

Comment: I would like the key and as a value, the value of the field 'value'

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas it was a little confusing at first, but I think with the help of your tool I could achieve it. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're merely getting the `value` of every `value` in the root object, you could use `map_values/1` to get those values.

```
map_values(.value)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
[ to_entries[] | .value = .value.value ] | from_entries
```

A simpler way:

```
with_entries(.value |= .value)
```

Check the result here:

https://jqplay.org/s/uHqfdPoF3e

Comment: You could simplify that approach considerably using this: `with_entries(.value |= .value)`